# Show that the limit of the expected value equals infinity

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I would like some help with the following problem. I have already done the first part. I believe that the second part is supposed to follow immediately from the first, but it is not obvious to me. Thanks for any help in advance.

> Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that
>
> $P(|X_1|\geq x) > 0$ for all x in $[0,\infty]$.
>
> (i) Prove that $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $|X_n|$ = $\infty$ a.c.
>
> (ii) Deduce from part (i) that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ $E(max_{1 \leq k \leq n}$ $|X_{k}|) = \infty$

Edit: Perhaps I need to use the monotone convergence theorem, though I don't see how I can in this situation. I may also need to use the Markov Inequality, but I am only saying that since the assumptions seem to set me up for its use.

Answer (score 0):

As lim sup $|X_n| = \infty$

for any $r, R$ $\exists$ $t : |X_{t+r}| > R$

and so $max_{s=1}^{t+r} |X_s| > R$

$R$ is unbounded and the expectation is at least $R$.